# Error 404 page cannot be found using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, apache, codeigniter, xampp

I am trying to use XAMPP to host my website on the domain https://localhost/media.einnovation.com but get the below error.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SFD2.png)

I have even tried going into the index of my local host and accessing the website that way but still the page will not load.

My website is built using CodeIgniter and has a.htaccess file that is set out as below.

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT, L]
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#    RewriteEngine On
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
#</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]


# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

My Apache and MySQL are operating fine on the XAMPP control panel with both having the green light.

My file directory for htdocs is shown below.

[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQMxv.png)

My code ignitore config.php is set as the following.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://media.einnovention.com';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
| 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
| 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
|
| WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Can anyone identify what the problem is?

Comment: have you set `$config['base_url'] = "https://localhost/media.einnovation.com";`

Comment: @KUMAR what is the name of the XAMPP file and folder location where I can replicate your suggestion?

Comment: in `config->config.php`

Comment: @KUMAR By defualt my $config['base_url'] =  was set as $config['base_url'] = '**http**://media.einnovention.com'; and when I even changed it to $config['base_url'] = '**https**://media.einnovention.com';  I am now getting the error response *media.einnovation.com’s server IP address could not be found.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the base URL of your site to be https://localhost/media.einnovation.com
you need to configure the base URL
$config['base_url'] = "https://localhost/media.einnovation.com";

You can also create a in routes.php file different routes to needle from media.einnovation.com to the controller you want.